# Defining a processing rate for an App Engine mail queue

Tags: google-app-engine, email, task-queue

I believe the following `queue.xml` represents the fastest processing rate you can configure for a Task Queue on App Engine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>fastest</name>
        <rate>50/s</rate>
        <bucket-size>5</bucket-size>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

I an app were to use this queue to send out emails would it violate the App Engine rate limit for mail services?

If so, what would be a preferable configuration for a mail queue?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your rate against the [API limits documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail) to see if you'd go over. You could certainly go over at that rate...

Comment: The answer also depends on if it's a paid app or not.